# Running and compile Spring Boot Multi Module Project

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I have a Spring Boot Multi Module Project (up vote a basic SpringBoot app. using Spring Initializer, embedded Tomcat, Thymeleaf template engine) 
Here the pom of the parent application:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.3.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <groupId>com.tdk-cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>tdk-cloud</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>

    <modules>   
        <module>tdk-core</module>
        <module>tdk-batch</module>
        <module>tdk-web</module>
    </modules>
..
```

Here 1 of the libraries:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<project xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd" xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">

  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <parent>
        <groupId>com.tdk-cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>tdk-cloud</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>

  <groupId>com.tdk.core</groupId>
  <artifactId>tdk-core</artifactId>
   <packaging>jar</packaging>    

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
  </properties>
  ...
```

and here another module

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<project xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd" xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">

  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <parent>
        <groupId>com.tdk-cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>tdk-cloud</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>

  <groupId>com.tdk.web</groupId>
  <artifactId>tdk-web</artifactId>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>


  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>


         <dependency>
            <groupId>com.tdk.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>tdk-core</artifactId>
            <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>           
        </dependency> 
...
```

But when I run  `mvn spring-boot:run` in the `com.tdk.web` module I got this error:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project tdk-web: Could not resolve dependencies for project com.tdkcloud.web:tdk-web:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT: Could not find artifact com.tdkcloud.core:tdk-core:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT -> [Help 1]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Error clearly says

```
Could not find artifact com.tdkcloud.core:tdk-core:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
```

**first** build tdk-core module, to make it available in your maven repo.

**after that** build tdk-web module.